# How to post image with axios?

Tags: javascript, flask, axios, multipartform-data

that's my try but it doesn't work.

I get error on backend: `file = request.files['file']` with `wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'file'`

my code on page to load image

```
$("#image-selector").change(function () {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    let dataURL = reader.result;
    $("#selected-image").attr("src", dataURL);
```

to send

```
  let image = $('#selected-image').get(0);

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', image);

  axios.post('/file', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log("TEST:", res.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

and that's python / flask backend code

```
@app.route('/file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> formData.append('file', image);
> ```

You need to post the **file** selected in the input element, not the input element itself.

```
formData.append('file', image.files[0]);
```

Comment: on image.files[0] I get: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: `#selected-image` is `<img>`

Comment: @cnd — The API you are using is designed for use with `<input type="file">` so the user can pick an image. An `<img>` element just displays an image from a URL. It isn't something the user has input (at least not directly). Perhaps you want to send it's `src` URL instead.

Comment: yes, it works if I use `let image = $("#image-selector").prop('files')[0];` interesting if I can use `<img>` thing same way? just `img.src` wasn't working

Comment: Is the image generated client side? If not, then it makes more sense to just send the URL and then process that as a URL on the server.

Comment: image uploaded by user on client and there is some default image in img, img changing code is first in question

Comment: Just use the image from the image-selector then. Trying to turn the rendered preview back into a file is far more effort then it is worth.